# How to properly react on angular FormGroup change?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

Unlike other forms I saw as example or the other forms in my project, I need to react on changes without any submit action, and to apply new values to my app on the fly.

```
this.form.get('my_input').valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  tap(() => this.form.markAllAsTouched()),
  filter(() => this.form.valid),
  tap(() => {
    // Do some stuff on other properties and labels
  })
).subscribe();
```

The code was inspired by the examples, but I did not manage to get anything executed unless I removed the `pipe` and RxJS operators into:

```
this.form.get('my_input').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
  // Do some stuff on other properties and labels
};
```

I still have trouble to understand exactly the good way of dealing with form changes and the good way to use pipes on the form.
I need to validate, to display errors on the inputs, to prevent the user from typing bad characters etc, but without any submit button. And the second code that seems to be working takes away those features of angular forms...

Edit: the form is declared with validators already but they just will not prevent any input from the user on the fly:

`[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\d+'), Validators.min(1)]`

Comment: Always you put the code **after** create the FormGroup should work. Be carefull, it's looks like you have two? formGroups? -form and formRange- But as Cristobal says, you can use a validator. A validator is executed always you "change" the input -really execute the (input) event. The typical is check, futhermore a FormGroup or FormControl is valid/invalid, if the formControl is touched -but it's not neccessary-. You see how the class ng-invalid is added to your input if the formControl is invalid

Answer (score 3):

yes, the pipe is tricky.

If you want to validate and display errors, I would recommend to you to use the validators included in form controls:

Here is a full tutorial with that https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

And then, use the simple subscription way to execute the other different functions